# How to compare a record date with current date?

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, authentication, comparison

In my login form, I am trying to compare the user's finish date with the current date to determine if they should be allowed into the system or not. Unfortunately my code isn't working.

My work is as follows;

```
If Cdate(DLookup("[FInish Date]", "Employee", "Userlogin = Me.TxtUserName.Value)) >= Date() then
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks pretty valid, but you've got numerous syntax errors in your `DLookUp` statement. It should be:

```
If CDate(DLookup("[Finish Date]", "Employee", "Userlogin = """ & Me.TxtUserName.Value & """")) >= Date() Then
```

Assuming Finish Date is a valid date field. 
Note that this doesn't handles `Null` and invalid dates properly. For a more robust approach:

```
Dim MyDate As Variant
MyDate = DLookup("[Finish Date]", "Employee", "Userlogin = """ & Me.TxtUserName.Value & """")
If IsDate(MyDate) Then
    If CDate(MyDate) >= Date() Then
```